# Agregar numeración de página usando itext en Android

Tags: android, itext

Realizando una App con la [librería itext](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android) de Android, consigo realizar a la perfección el PDF, pero ahora me gustaría ir un poco mas allá y poner arriba/abajo a la derecha "pagina X de Y" para que el lector se situé en la pagina en la que está.

He leído por internet muchas opciones, casi todas pasan por en `PdfPageEventHelper`, pero ninguna termina de funcionar al 100%.

Espero que alguien pueda mostrar un ejemplo sencillo y claro que pueda ayudarnos a todos a implementarlo en nuestros proyectos.